# How to get linked resource from a web page?

Tags: c#, html, httpwebrequest

I'm writing a small application where I need to get the linked resources from a web page e.g

```
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://name.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" /> 
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://name.wordpress.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
```

the easiest way would be to parse the page and get what I wanted, but I'm looking best way to do it.

Is there any direct way to get RDS content?
Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a small project and you already have working code to parse the page, use it.

If you are looking for a better/recommended way to parse the HTML of a page, consider using something more mature like the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I knew about HAP somehow it did not occurred to me to use it!